# Conditional render SVG with styled component

Tags: styled-components

I need to change the color of a SVG with styled-component.

```
import styled from "styled-component";
import {ifProp} from "styled-tools";
import arrowSVG from "./assets/arrow.svg";

const Arrow = styled(arrowSVG)`
   fill: ${ props => props.shouldFill ? red : white };
`;

// Then use it like this:
<Arrow shouldFill={false}>
<Arrow shouldFill>
```

However, it won't work. Because the time I do `styled(arrowSVG)`, all props will be passed down to arrow.svg, so React will give a warning like: can't recognize `shouldFill` as a valid DOM property.

How to overcome this without creating a new function to handle the conditional checking? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if you can use SVG icons directly as you have mentioned in your question.
Also, it will depend on how you import SVG icon like in my case it got imported as 'src' for the icon on the code sandbox.
It is better if you create Icon as React component and pass fill as a prop to it or use one of the existing SVG icon libraries out there.

I have created a Code Sandbox for the same where I have created the SVG icon as a component which accepts fill as a prop which should solve your use case.

[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/0qzyr6q5y0)

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe not the optimal solution but it solved my similar problem. Adding a wrapper styled div.

```
import ArrowSVG from "./assets/arrow.svg";

const ArrowFrame = styled.div`
   svg {
      fill: ${ props => props.shouldFill ? red : white };
   }
`;

<ArrowFrame shouldFill={false}><ArrowSVG /></ArrowFrame />
<ArrowFrame shouldFill><ArrowSVG /></ArrowFrame />
```